# Magento update database from dev to live

Tags: php, mysql, git, magento

I want to know the best practice to update my database from the dev site to the live one (or stage).

Actually, I do a complete mysqldump of my dev database and then I reimport it to the stage server.

But when my website will be live, I cannot do that anymore because there will be news orders and customer in my live database...

So, I try to use the magento import/export profiles, but this is slow and I often get errors. (like 500 error with my cgi script) or the prices aren't correct.

I also try to use magmi, this is faster, but I also have a lot of erros (missing data, bad categories).

I think the best practice would be to migrate all my database, except tables containing information about customers and orders.

But I don't see any post around this so I'm not sure it's the best method.

I use Magento 1.8.0

Comment: Take a look @ http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252/what-is-the-best-deploy-strategy

Comment: Thanks, I will read it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use database migrations. Look how others have done it, it's quite simple to roll your own. For example [doctrine migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html).